# Kafka CooperativeStickyAssignor revokes/assigns partition in one rebalance cycle

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have an application that runs 6 consumers in parallel. I am getting some unexpected results when I use `CooperativeStickyAssignor`.
If I understand the mechanism correctly, if the consumer looses partition in one rebalance cycle, the partition will be assigned in the next rebalance cycle.

This assumption is based on the [RebalanceProtocol](https://kafka.apache.org/31/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/ConsumerPartitionAssignor.RebalanceProtocol.html) documentation and few blog posts that describe the protocol, like [this one](https://www.confluent.io/blog/cooperative-rebalancing-in-kafka-streams-consumer-ksqldb/) on Confluent blog.

> The assignor should not reassign any owned partitions immediately, but
> instead may indicate consumers the need for partition revocation so
> that the revoked partitions can be reassigned to other consumers in
> the next rebalance event. This is designed for sticky assignment logic
> which attempts to minimize partition reassignment with cooperative
> adjustments.

> Any member that revoked partitions then rejoins the group, triggering
> a second rebalance so that its revoked partitions can be assigned.
> Until then, these partitions are unowned and unassigned.

These are the logs from the application that uses `protocol='cooperative-sticky'`. In the same rebalance cycle (`generationId=640`) `partition 74` moves from `consumer-3` to `consumer-4`. I omitted the lines that are logged by the other 4 consumers.

Mind that the log is in reverse(bottom to top)

```
2022-12-14 11:18:24   1 --- [consumer-3] x.y.z.MyRebalanceHandler1   : New partition assignment: partition-59, seek to min common offset: 85120524
2022-12-14 11:18:24   1 --- [consumer-3] x.y.z.MyRebalanceHandler2   : Partitions [partition-59] assigned successfully
2022-12-14 11:18:24   1 --- [consumer-3] x.y.z.MyRebalanceHandler1   : Partitions assigned: [partition-59]
2022-12-14 11:18:24   1 --- [consumer-3] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=partition-3-my-client-id-my-group-id, groupId=my-group-id] Adding newly assigned partitions: partition-59
2022-12-14 11:18:24   1 --- [consumer-3] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=partition-3-my-client-id-my-group-id, groupId=my-group-id] Notifying assignor about the new Assignment(partitions=[partition-59])
2022-12-14 11:18:24   1 --- [consumer-3] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=partition-3-my-client-id-my-group-id, groupId=my-group-id] Request joining group due to: need to revoke partitions [partition-26, partition-74] as indicated by the current assignment and re-join
2022-12-14 11:18:24   1 --- [consumer-3] x.y.z.MyRebalanceHandler2   : Partitions [partition-26, partition-74] revoked successfully
2022-12-14 11:18:24   1 --- [consumer-3] x.y.z.MyRebalanceHandler1   : Finished removing partition data
2022-12-14 11:18:24   1 --- [consumer-4] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=partition-4-my-client-id-my-group-id, groupId=my-group-id] (Re-)joining group
2022-12-14 11:18:24   1 --- [consumer-4] x.y.z.MyRebalanceHandler1   : New partition assignment: partition-74, seek to min common offset: 107317730
2022-12-14 11:18:24   1 --- [consumer-4] x.y.z.MyRebalanceHandler2   : Partitions [partition-74] assigned successfully
2022-12-14 11:18:24   1 --- [consumer-4] x.y.z.MyRebalanceHandler1   : Partitions assigned: [partition-74]
2022-12-14 11:18:24   1 --- [consumer-4] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=partition-4-my-client-id-my-group-id, groupId=my-group-id] Adding newly assigned partitions: partition-74
2022-12-14 11:18:24   1 --- [consumer-4] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=partition-4-my-client-id-my-group-id, groupId=my-group-id] Notifying assignor about the new Assignment(partitions=[partition-74])
2022-12-14 11:18:24   1 --- [consumer-4] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=partition-4-my-client-id-my-group-id, groupId=my-group-id] Request joining group due to: need to revoke partitions [partition-57] as indicated by the current assignment and re-join
2022-12-14 11:18:24   1 --- [consumer-4] x.y.z.MyRebalanceHandler2   : Partitions [partition-57] revoked successfully
2022-12-14 11:18:24   1 --- [consumer-4] x.y.z.MyRebalanceHandler1   : Finished removing partition data
2022-12-14 11:18:22   1 --- [consumer-3] x.y.z.MyRebalanceHandler1   : Partitions revoked: [partition-26, partition-74]
2022-12-14 11:18:22   1 --- [consumer-3] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=partition-3-my-client-id-my-group-id, groupId=my-group-id] Revoke previously assigned partitions partition-26, partition-74
2022-12-14 11:18:22   1 --- [consumer-3] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=partition-3-my-client-id-my-group-id, groupId=my-group-id] Updating assignment with\n\tAssigned partitions:                       [partition-59]\n\tCurrent owned partitions:                  [partition-26, partition-74]\n\tAdded partitions (assigned - owned):       [partition-59]\n\tRevoked partitions (owned - assigned):     [partition-26, partition-74]
2022-12-14 11:18:22   1 --- [consumer-3] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=partition-3-my-client-id-my-group-id, groupId=my-group-id] Successfully synced group in generation Generation{generationId=640, memberId='partition-3-my-client-id-my-group-id-c31afd19-3f22-43cb-ad07-9088aa98d3af', protocol='cooperative-sticky'}
2022-12-14 11:18:22   1 --- [consumer-3] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=partition-3-my-client-id-my-group-id, groupId=my-group-id] Successfully joined group with generation Generation{generationId=640, memberId='partition-3-my-client-id-my-group-id-c31afd19-3f22-43cb-ad07-9088aa98d3af', protocol='cooperative-sticky'}
2022-12-14 11:18:22   1 --- [consumer-4] x.y.z.MyRebalanceHandler1   : Partitions revoked: [partition-57]
2022-12-14 11:18:22   1 --- [consumer-4] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=partition-4-my-client-id-my-group-id, groupId=my-group-id] Revoke previously assigned partitions partition-57
2022-12-14 11:18:22   1 --- [consumer-4] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=partition-4-my-client-id-my-group-id, groupId=my-group-id] Updating assignment with\n\tAssigned partitions:                       [partition-74]\n\tCurrent owned partitions:                  [partition-57]\n\tAdded partitions (assigned - owned):       [partition-74]\n\tRevoked partitions (owned - assigned):     [partition-57]
2022-12-14 11:18:21   1 --- [id-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=partition-4-my-client-id-my-group-id, groupId=my-group-id] Successfully synced group in generation Generation{generationId=640, memberId='partition-4-my-client-id-my-group-id-ae2af665-edc9-4a8e-b658-98372d142477', protocol='cooperative-sticky'}
2022-12-14 11:18:21   1 --- [consumer-4] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=partition-4-my-client-id-my-group-id, groupId=my-group-id] Successfully joined group with generation Generation{generationId=640, memberId='partition-4-my-client-id-my-group-id-ae2af665-edc9-4a8e-b658-98372d142477', protocol='cooperative-sticky'}
```

What am I missing here?

I expect that the partition gets revoked in one rebalance cycle and gets assigned in the next.

Kafka client version is 3.2.1.

Comment: Hi, did you figure out what was wrong? I'm hitting some similar problems

Comment: Hello @Thomas. I ended up creating https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-14639 where nice people who maintain Kafka confirmed an issue and apparently solved it few hours ago with this PR. https://github.com/apache/kafka/pull/13550

Comment: awesome! thanks for having followed up on this